# Unity " Image is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.UI.Image' and 'UnityEngine.UIElements.Image' " Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, 2d

the piece of code causing the error,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class OyunKontrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject secilmisText;
    public GameObject devretPanel;
    public GameObject yaziTuraText;
    public int sonuc = 1;
    public int sira;
    public string yaziTuraCikti = "Tura";
    public string secilmisName;
    public Color player1Color;
    public Color player2Color;
    public Color player3Color;
    public Color player4Color;

    void Start()
    {
        sira = 1;
        print("Saldırmak veya almak istediğiniz şehri seçiniz...");
        secilmisName = null;
**        player1Color = GameObject.Find("Player1").GetComponent<Image>().color;
        player2Color = GameObject.Find("Player2").GetComponent<Image>().color;
        player3Color = GameObject.Find("Player3").GetComponent<Image>().color;
        player4Color = GameObject.Find("Player4").GetComponent<Image>().color;**
    }
```

the bolded codes are the part where the error is rooted.

how can i fix this?

I tried deleting and rewriting the code but the error was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Image class exists in both the `UIElement` reference and the `Unity UI`, and it cannot distinguish which one this class belongs to. According to your code, this class should belong to Unity UI, so it is better to remove using UI Element.

```cs
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
```